# Problem in finding output data of NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, physics

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a = 4372*0.53*10^-8;
n = 5*10^18;
kF = (3*Pi*n)^(1/3);
X = 0.3*a*kF;
wz = 2 *Pi*230;
wx = 2 *Pi*40;
wy = 2 *Pi*40;


EqSet = NDSolve[{bx''[t] + wx^2*bx[t] - 
      wx^2/bx[t]*1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])^(2/3) +3/2*X*wx^2/
       bx[t]*(1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])^(2/3) - 1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])) ==  0,

    by''[t] + wx^2*by[t] - wy^2/by[t]*1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])^(2/3) +3/2*X*wy^2/
       by[t]*(1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])^(2/3) - 1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])) == 0,

    bz''[t] + wz^2*bz[t] - wz^2/bz[t]*1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])^(2/3) + 3/2*X*wz^2/
       bz[t]*(1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])^(2/3) - 1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])) ==  0,
    bx[0] == 1, by[0] == 1, bz[0] == 1, bx'[0] == 0, by'[0] == 0, bz'[0] == 0} ,
                                        {bx, by, bz}, {t, 0, 10}] ;
Plot[Evaluate[bx[t] /. EqSet], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Can anybody help me to figure out the issue in the above mentioned code that I cannot get any data on graph?  My goal is to simulate equation (24) and to reproduce Fig.3 of the paper "Expansion of an interacting Fermi gas", which is available at [arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0208150v3.pdf](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0208150v3.pdf).

(*reduced*)

```
wz = 2 *Pi*230;
wx = 2 *Pi*40;
γ = 2/3;
EqSet = NDSolve[{bx''[t] + wx^2*bx[t] - wx^2/bx[t]*1/(bx[t]*bz[t])^γ == 0
     bz''[t] + wz^2*bz[t] - wz^2/bz[t]*1/(bx[t]*bz[t])^γ == 0,
     bx[0] == 1, bz[0] == 1, bx'[0] == 0, bz'[0] == 0},
     {bx, bz}, {t, 0, 10}, MaxSteps -> 10000]
```

Comment: I got a straight line at `y=1` in M9 (Linux) :)

Comment: Looks like in the second equation the `wx` should be a `wy`, but that doesn't change the straight line in the `Plot`, which you don't want I guess. Would be nice to know, what you expect to get!?

Comment: my final task is in fact to get the graph between this ratio "R = (by*wx)/(bz*wy)" and "t" that's why first I tried to get graph just for bx or by.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to these equations and their associated boundary conditions is, indeed, `bx`, `by`, `bz` all equal to one, just as computed by `NDSolve`.  This can be seen from

```
Unevaluated[
    {D[bx[t], t, t] + wx^2*bx[t] - wx^2/bx[t]*1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])^(2/3) + 
       3/2*X*wx^2/bx[t]*(1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])^(2/3) - 1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])) == 0,
     D[by[t], t, t] + wx^2*by[t] - wy^2/by[t]*1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])^(2/3) + 
       3/2*X*wy^2/by[t]*(1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])^(2/3) - 1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])) == 0,
     D[bz[t], t, t] + wz^2*bz[t] - wz^2/bz[t]*1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])^(2/3) + 
       3/2*X*wz^2/bz[t]*(1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])^(2/3) - 1/(bx[t]*by[t]*bz[t])) ==  0}] 
     /. {bx[t] -> 1, by[t] -> 1, bz[t] -> 1}

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

plus a similar comparison with the boundary conditions.  Changing the boundary conditions will give different answers, of course.

**Addendum: Plotting Ratio of Dependent Variables**

There are a variety of ways to plot the ratio requested in the question and again in comments.  One is to plot the ratio of the actual values computed by `NDSolve`, which is accomplished by,

```
ListPlot[{Flatten[bx["Grid"] /. EqSet], (wz/wx) Divide @@@ (Flatten[
    {bx["ValuesOnGrid"], bz["ValuesOnGrid"]} /. EqSet, 1] // Transpose)} // Transpose]
```

[image]

Of course, the plot is not very interesting for the boundary conditions chosen.

**Addendum: Explanation and Alternative**

At the request of [Ren](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/39038/ren),

```
Flatten[bx["Grid"] /. EqSet]
(* {0., 0.00102648, 0.00205297, 1.00205, 2.00205, 3.00205, 4.00205, 
    5.00205, 6.00205, 7.00205, 8.00205, 9.00103, 10.} *)
```

provides the values of the independent variable used by `NDSolve`, and

```
Flatten[bx["ValuesOnGrid"] /. EqSet]
(* {1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.} *)
```

provides the corresponding values of a dependent variable.  `Transpose` converts, in this case, pairs of arrays into arrays of pairs on which `Divide` and, later, `ListPlot` can work, and finally the result

```
{Flatten[bx["Grid"] /. EqSet], (wz/wx) Divide @@@ (Flatten[
    {bx["ValuesOnGrid"], bz["ValuesOnGrid"]} /. EqSet, 1] // Transpose)} // Transpose
(* {{0., 5.75}, {0.00102648, 5.75}, {0.00205297, 5.75}, {1.00205, 5.75}, 
    {2.00205, 5.75}, {3.00205, 5.75}, {4.00205, 5.75}, {5.00205, 5.75}, 
    {6.00205, 5.75}, {7.00205, 5.75}, {8.00205, 5.75}, {9.00103, 5.75}, {10., 5.75}} *)
```

which `ListPlot` can handle without difficulty.  This approach may be slow, if the number of values of the independent variable, computed by

```
Length[Flatten[bx["Grid"] /. EqSet]]
(* 11 *)
```

is too large.  Then, `Table` might be used instead.

```
ListPlot[Table[{i, ((wz bx[t]) /. Flatten@EqSet /. t -> i)/
    ((wx bz[t]) /. Flatten@EqSet /. t -> i)}, {i, 0, 10, .5}]]
```

which gives a plot like that above but with `21` uniformly spaced points.  There are many variants on these approaches.

**(reduced)**

The recently added *reduced* code at the end of the question yields the same plots, once a comma is added between the first and second equations in `NDSolve`.

Comment: it gives values but when I want to plot this ratio with "t" then it again did not give any graph , may be problem with it,s graph command

Comment: ARatioPlot = ListPlot[ARatio, PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {0, 6}}]

Comment: @Ren  Simply taking the ratio of interpolating functions, `(bx[t]/bz[t])/.EqSet`, does not work, because `InterpolationFunction`s do not combine that way.  I provided a straightforward solution as an addition to my earlier answer, and other approaches are described elsewhere in StackExchange.  By the way, I notice that no one has sent you the usual welcome message, so I am doing so above.  Best wishes.

Comment: @Ren  I have addressed one of your comments in an addition to my answer.  To compute to larger `t`, add the option `MaxSteps ->100000` or larger to `NDSolve`.  I presume that you now are using different boundary conditions.  I experimented with that myself and obtained solutions that oscillated wildly, which may be why you need large `MaxSteps`.  Be warned that the calculation may be very slow.  If my answer addresses your original question well, please remember to accept it   Thanks.

Comment: 'wz = 2 *Pi*230;
wx = 2 *Pi*40;
\[Gamma] = 2/3;
EqSet = NDSolve[{bx''[t] + wx^2*bx[t] - 
     wx^2/bx[t]*1/(bx[t]*bz[t])^\[Gamma] == 0
                      bz''[t] + wz^2*bz[t] - 
     wz^2/bz[t]*1/(bx[t]*bz[t])^\[Gamma] == 0,
                                    bx[0] == 1, bz[0] == 1, 
   bx'[0] == 0, bz'[0] == 0} ,
                                       {bx, bz}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  MaxSteps -> 10000] '

Comment: The paper is available at http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0208150v3.pdf   with title "Expansion of an interacting Fermi gas" and I want to simulate equation (24) of this paper and want to reproduce Fig.3 of the paper

Comment: in equation (24) index "i" means, x, y, z, means three coupled equations. in Fig.3 vertical axis is Rx/Rz =(bx*wz)/(bz*wx) and horizontal axis is wx*t

Comment: Also the boundary conditions for this system are bx[0]=1 and bx ' [0]=0

Comment: @Ren  I moved your reference to your question and reformatted your added code.  In doing so, I noticed that the code lacks a comma at the end of the first line.  If you add it, the code runs fine but once again gives results equal to `1`.  However, it is clear from Fig 3 in the reference that boundary conditions are not what you have specified.  May I suggest that you delete any comments above that no longer are relevant.  Also, I believe that you now have a physics problem, which you could ask in the physics part of StackExchange.